# xpath select child element changing depth dynamically

Tags: html, xpath

This is html source i have:

```
<td class="Ap">
    <div>
        <div><textarea></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div attribute="true">
            <div><img src="blabla" width="412" height="309"></img></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

How can i get the **child `<img>` element based in `<div attribute="true">`** if the `<img>` changing it's depth  like it can be for example:

```
<td class="Ap">
    <div>
        <div><textarea></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div attribute="true">
          <div>
           <div>
            <div><img src="blabla" width="412" height="309"></img></div>
           <div>
          <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: how are you retrieving the xpath ? Are you using relative path or absolute xpath? Relative xpath will save you the trouble. Please post your solution you've used so far

Comment: i don't know how to make itm thats why posted here. smth like `//div[@attribute='true']/following-child::img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options for you:

```
//img[ancestor::div/@attribute='true']
```

or

```
//div[@attribute='true']//img
```

or

```
//div[@attribute='true']/descendant::img
```

All of these will find all the img nodes contained below the div